# How can I use catkin package resources with the devel space?

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble using package resources from the devel space of a catkin workspace.  After I successfully run `catkin_make`, I have new build and devel folders.  If I source `ws/devel/setup.bash`, I can then run binaries and use libraries, scripts, etc as I'd expect.  But what about package-relative resources?

**First question:** How to I specify these resources in the package's `CMakeLists.txt`?  I wasn't able to find any examples in the docs.  Here's what I've been doing:

```
$ cat ws/source/path/to/my_package/CMakeLists.txt
...
install(
  DIRECTORY my_resources DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
...
```

(but of course this isn't used for the devel space, right?)

**Second question:** How do I find these resources if I'm using the devel space?

My first try was `rospack`.  Here's the result:

```
$ rospack find my_package
ws/build/path/to/my_package/catkin_generated/stamps/my_package
```

This location doesn't hold any resources (copies or links to the source space).  (Or should it?)

I also stumbled upon `catkin_find`.  Here's the result:

```
$ catkin_find my_package
ws/devel/share/my_package
ws/source/path/to/my_package
```

I suppose the second one is what I want?  Is this always the right thing to do?

Sidenote: It appears through some magic that `roslaunch` knows where to look for launch files (or does it search everything in the `catkin_find` list?).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51785/how-can-i-use-catkin-package-resources-with-the-devel-space?/) by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 462 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are right that things listed in CMakeLists.txt with an install(...) macro does not automatically get moved into the devel space.

catkin_find can help you, it takes more arguments, like:

```
$ catkin_find roscpp package.xml
$ catkin_find roscpp srv/Empty.srv
```

It will search folders in a specific order to find what you look for. catkin_find is based on the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and the contents of a file called .catkin in your devel space.

Not sure whether there is a cleaner way to refer to other packages (cmake, python).

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cdellin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3806/cdellin/) on 2013-01-09**:
Fantastic! This was just what I needed.  This was difficult to find because the catkin_find usage message uses the word "project", whereas it would make more sense to me (as a ROS user, not a cakin dev) if it were the word "package" instead.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you need a way to find these resource in cases where you do not know if the package is catkinized or not you can use this code which works for all ROS distros:

````
import rospkg
rp = rospkg.RosPack()
path = rp.get_path('my_package')```
````

The resulting path will either point to the source folder or the install folder of the package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1